Cloud Vision API send response "com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: No image " (Kotlin Android)
I am a newbie in the Cloud Vision Api and using it for my android app development to translate urdu text from the image but every time, I hit my google cloud function i get exception

com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: No image present.

However I've decoded my base64 encoded image and found correct image.
I am going crazy finding solution of what went wrong.
Here is my firebase cloud function code in index.js:
> exports.annotateImage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =\> {
>    if (!context.auth) {
>      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
>      "unauthenticated","annotateImage must be called while authenticated.",
>    );
> }
>     console.log("data " + data); // Can't find these logs entry on google cloud console
>     logger.log("dataRequest" + data);
>
>     try {
>     return await client.annotateImage(JSON.parse(data)); // I've tried removing JSON.parse method     but same  exception occurred.
>     catch (e) {
>     throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", e.message, e.details);
>      }
>      });

My android client request :
{
>    "image":{
>       "content":"/9j/4AAQ........(base64image)=="
>    },
>    "features":[
>       {
>          "type":"TEXT_DETECTION"
>       }
>    ],
>    "imageContext":{
>       "languageHints":[
>          "ur"
>       ]
>    }
> }

I have followed firebase documentation
My image should read the text from the image but whenever i call annotateImage cloud function (as per documentation) it gives No image present exception.
